# build_runner watch does not exit after builds

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

Different from

```
build_runner build
```

command,

```
build_runner watch
```

does not exit after its build.

So, every time I use it, I type Ctrl+c to exit. Any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `watch`: Runs a persistent build server that watches the files system for edits and does rebuilds as necessary.

Means `watch` make it easier when we don't want to type the command for every changes.

You have to exit the `watch` manually. You can use `build` it just runs single time.

You can find more about [usage](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner#usage).